# Can Pakistani Travel to Gibraltar with Morocco visit visa?

Tags: visas, pakistani-citizens, morocco, gibraltar

Can Pakistani Travel to Gibraltar with Morocco Visit Visa and holding ordinary Pakistani passport or Need to apply Gibraltar visit visa separately from home country.

Answer (score 2):

Gibraltar is a British Overseas Territory. As a general rule, travellers who require a visa to enter the UK will also require a visa to enter Gibraltar. According to https://www.gibraltar.gov.gi/new/visas-and-immigration you will require a visa. Your Moroccan Visitor visa makes no difference.